# Can we have a notification as in fade out(not in inbox) message on comment deletions only for the owner alone as a success response to deletion?

Tags: feature-request, deleted-comments

Recently I posted a comment on my own answer trying to help a user. After few minutes I realised that I made a mistake in my comment, so I wanted to edit it, which was not possible because the five minute grace period was already over. So I tried deleting my own comment and reposting it.

Now when I did that at the same moment a new comment appeared which was almost of the same length which I had posted, and the user name with the same initial as mine, which I ended up flagging thinking that it was my own comment which I was unable to delete.

Had I seen a small notification that the comment has been deleted I would have not made the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a scenario in which a moderator removed comments from an entire question for moderator-specific reasons.  *Every* user, even those not directly involved in the rationale, would be notified that some comment was deleted.

What would happen *next* would be a flood of comments on that question saying, "Why was my comment deleted?"  Or, you get a dozen annoyed questions here on Meta behind being notified when content is removed, which would *greatly* deviate from the common pattern of notifications (good news travels fast).

I don't think this would be a good thing to add.  You can look at it like this, though:  your comment doesn't need to be edited anymore.

Comment: What I meant was a small popup, or message for the user alone who is deleting his comment, which fades out in 2-3 secs saying that comment is deleted successfully.

Comment: @Sahil you do get a popup confirming that you want it deleted....followed by the comment being deleted. if there was an error you get a red popup

Comment: @Memor-X: You're absolutely right.  Although it's "comment" in this scenario, not question.

Comment: @Memor-X:  Yes, I just had to test.  My mind played tricks on me today.

Comment: Yes we do get a popup, I just explained my scenario of how I ended up thinking the comment was not deleted and then flagged a wrong user's comment. it's my badluck should have seen it again that the comment was already deleted. But I guess a small fade in msg could have saved me. Thanks a lot, just wanted to know.